# MySQL add avg of count by id to existing select with id

Tags: mysql, sql

Im not even sure what the title of this question should be but lets start out with my data.

I have a table of users who have taken a few lessons while belonging to a particular training center.

**lesson table**

```
id | lesson_id | user_id | has_completed
----------------------------------------
1  | asdf3314  |    2    |      1
2  | d13saf12  |    2    |      1
3  | a33adff5  |    2    |      0
4  | a33adff5  |    1    |      1
5  | d13saf12  |    1    |      0
```

**user table**

```
id | center_id | ...
----------------------------------------
1  |    20     | ...
2  |    30     | ...
```

**training center table**

```
id | center_name | ...
----------------------------------------
20 |  learn.co   | ...
30 |  teach.co   | ...
```

I've written a small chunk but am now stuck as I don't know how to proceed. This statement gets the counted total of completed lessons per user. it then figures the average completed value from a center id. if two users belong to a center and have completed 3 lessons and 2 lessons it finds the average of 3 and 2 then returns that.

```
SELECT
    FLOOR(AVG(a.total)) AS avg_completion,
FROM
(SELECT 
    user_id,
    user.center_id,
    count(user_id) AS total 
    FROM lesson 
    LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = user_id 
    WHERE is_completed = 1 AND center_id = 2
    GROUP BY user_id) AS a;
```

The question I have is how do I loop through the training centers table and also append average data from similar select statement as above to each center that is queried. I cant seem to pass the center id down to the subquery so there must be a fundamentally different way to achieve the same query but also loop through training centers.

An example of desired result:

```
center.id | avg_completion | ...training center table
-----------------------------------------------------
     20   |       2        | ...
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`? Can a lesson have a `user_id` that isn't in `user`? And when you use `LEFT JOIN`, you should put any restrictions on the second table in the `ON` clause. If you put `center_id = 2` in the `WHERE` clause, you'll filter out all the null rows when there's no match.

Comment: the AND center_id = 2 aspect is where I am able to fetch a single companys avg. the final query should omit this as it will be looping through all centers. so you are right to point this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main query needs to select `a.center_id` and then use `GROUP BY center_id`. You can then join it with the `training_center` table.

```
SELECT c.*, x.avg_completion
FROM training_center AS c
JOIN (
    SELECT
        a.center_id,
        FLOOR(AVG(a.total)) AS avg_completion
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            user_id
            user.center_id,
            count(*) AS total 
        FROM lesson 
        JOIN user ON user.id = user_id 
        WHERE is_completed = 1 AND center_id = 2
        GROUP BY user_id) AS a
    GROUP BY a.center_id) AS x
ON x.center_id = c.id
```

Comment: Im sure this is the closest answer I am receiving the FULL_GROUP_BY error message because of the a.center_id. what is the best way to write this where that is taken into account?

Comment: I forgot `GROUP BY a.center_id`.

Comment: perfect! this works. I changed the join to left join as I still need the other centers that dont have averages. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
select u.center_id, count(*) as num_users,
       sum(l.has_completed) as num_completed,
       avg(l.has_completed) as completed_ratio
from lesson l join
     user u
     on l.user_id = u.id
group by u.center_id
```